# QEMU error on pfSense instalation

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, pfsense

I'm trying to install pfSense using QEMU on EVE-NG. I'm using the EVE-NG [documentation](https://www.eve-ng.net/index.php/documentation/howtos/howto-add-pfsense-fw-2-4/) for pfSense 2.4.x, i did all the steps, but in the installation part

```
/opt/qemu/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -hda install.img -hdb virtioa.qcow2 -nographic
```

this error occurs:

[image]

Any solution for this? Thx.

Comment: Please copy/paste error messages rather than a screenshot in the future.
Possible meta-duplicate? https://superuser.com/questions/1380885/custom-memory-allocation-vtable-not-supported-trying-to-use-qemu

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to rename .iso file to .img and
run /opt/qemu/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -hda install.img -hdb virtioa.qcow2 -nographic it will show you this error.

Try to use .img file example: pfSense-CE-memstick-serial-2.4.4-RELEASE-p3-amd64.img